# What is the sum of $T[n] = C * \sum_{i=1}^n k^ix^\frac{i(1-i)}{2}$ for $x > 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Im trying to get the following sum:

$T[n] = C \sum_{i=1}^n k^ix^\frac{i(1-i)}{2} = Ck^1+ Ck^2x^1+Ck^3x^3+Ck^4x^6+...+k^nx^\frac{n(1-n)}{2}$ for $x > 1$

Both $C$, $k > 1$, and $x$ are constants.

It seems to me as if it is a discrete logistic function but I don't know how to get there...

[This is what I get for $C = 70$, $k=1.3$ and $x=1.005$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqzOz.png)

Comment: Did you mean $i - 1$ or $1 - i$ in the power of $x$? If the latter, $T(n)\in\Theta\left(x\right)$ since $\forall i > 1$, each term that is added to the sum is $\dfrac1{x^{\frac{i(i - 1)}{2}}} < x,\,\forall x > 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $T(n)\in\Theta(1)$ since the largest term is $x^0 = 1$ for $i = 1$.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, I tried to edit the question itself.